# How to trace executed code lines in a java project?

Tags: java, debugging

I am working on a simulation project running on java. I want to put out different executed lines relating to different configurations of parameters. For instance, I want to know what different lines would be running when I change the value of one specific parameter. What I want is basically similar to adding println following each line of code, like this:

```
list.put(key, value);
System.out.println("line: 1 in file: main");
function(arg);
System.out.println("line: 2 in file: main");
int i;
System.out.println("line: 3 in file: main");
```

As it is practically impossible to add these lines, I just want to know if there is any tool or debugging option that could facilitate it, preferably within the JetBrains IDEs.

Noted: I realized the trace module in python produces such a thing.

Comment: You can use the debugger that comes with Intellij/Pycharm or whatever IDE you have.
Just start the app in debug mode

Comment: It runs the same as run mode except it would stop in the breakpoints, I need some way that shows the executed lines altogether at the end of running. Using debugging mode is longsome and infeasible concerning this massive project code.

Comment: That's not the case.
You can use stepping for debugging to trace the lines of codes executed.
Hope this helps: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#step-into

You can read the full article to have a better understanding on how to use the debugger.

If you don't want to use the debugger, the other option is to use logging/souts.

Comment: Then how can I find the difference between the two different runs? I mean as I already familiar with debugging mode there are no such logs along with, or maybe I have not got your point. And what about the latter one? Would you please explain logging/souts more?

Comment: With stepping, you can evaluate the lines/see the stack of the program/see the variables/change the variable values etc. It would make more sense if you go through the link.
Logging/SysOuts are similar to what you are doing right now.

Comment: Oh. Actually I know how debugging mode works. The problem is the project is massive and contains enormous lines and functions which is possibly impractical to trace and stepping by eyes. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217850/discussion-between-vishal-and-ali-rasaii).

Comment: There may be some useful insights and links here [How do you dive into large code bases?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6395/357510). To be sure these are not answers to your _specific_ question - but they discuss the underlying situation (_"massive project code"_). Using a debugger, and talking to those with knowledge, are mentioned repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Using IBM JVM you can achieve it: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=component-tracing-java-applications  with the -Xtrace option. Otherwise you can add a logging aspect https://www.infoworld.com/article/2072449/logging-method-entry-exit-with-spring-aspectj.html . There was also an excellent product btrace, but I think it's no longer supported. But as already stated in many comments, the easiest way is to remote debug and put a breakpoint.